# problem using variable in nginx location directive

Tags: nginx, proxypass

good evening. i have a question regarding nginx and it is related to the location directive. i currently have this configuration in nginx

```
server {  
  server_name ~^(?<account>.+)\.domain\.com$;
  root /var/www/html/folder-frontend/;
  index index.html;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/$account-access.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/$account-access.log;

  location / {
      try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  location /$account-backend/ {
      proxy_pass http://service-backend/;
      proxy_set_header HOST $account-backend.domain.co;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }
}
```

this means that I have several domains with the ending tenant.domain.com(app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com). with the expression (?.+) I am getting part of the string in the url that interests me and then in the location directive use it to make a proxypass and redirect the requests. but this is not working, I know because when I put in the location what interests me (in this case would be location /app1-backend/) if redirects to the backend service that I have listening in another nginx.

My doubt is, can I use a variable in the location directive of nginx? I tried it that way specified and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a variable as `location` directive argument, even in a regex matching ones. You can try a workaround like

```
server {  
    server_name ~^(?<account>.+)\.domain\.com$;
    root /var/www/html/folder-frontend/;
    index index.html;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/$account-access.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/$account-access.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/(?<prefix>[^.]+)-backend(?<suffix>/.*) {
        if ($prefix != $account) {
            return 404;
        }
        proxy_pass http://service-backend$suffix$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header HOST $prefix-backend.domain.co;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```